# Simulating C function static variable in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a function called `generateUID`, which is external C function connected via FFI.
This function generates new unique id for each call, but I need one uid for entire program. If I were using C/C++, I would've made a function like this one.

```
int getUID() {
    static int uid = generateUID();
    return uid;
}
```

So that I can use this like this

```
int foo() { return getUID() + 1; }
int bar() { return getUID() + 2; }
int main() {
    printf("%d\n", foo() + bar();
}
```

In haskell, I used function like this

```
getUID :: IO Int
getUID = generateUID -- this is attached to C lib with FFI
foo = (+1) <$> getUID
bar = (+2) <$> getUID
main = (+) <$> foo <*> bar >>= print
```

However, `getUID` is called twice if I use this code. The only solution that I know of is to merge them into one `do` notation, but in my real code, `foo` and `bar` are reused too frequently to be merged to other function.

How can I make my haskell version `getUID` call `generateUID` only once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following trick, adapted from [this method for defining global mutable variables](https://wiki.haskell.org/Top_level_mutable_state).  For your application, you don't need a *mutable* variable, but by using `unsafePerformIO` in a top-level definition, you can force the IO action `generateUID` to be called only once and its return value memoized for future calls:

```
getUID :: Int
{-# NOINLINE getUID #-}
getUID = unsafePerformIO generateUID
```

For example, the following complete example will re-use the same random number generated by the first `getUID` call for any future calls:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module Uid where

import System.IO.Unsafe

foreign import ccall "stdlib.h random" generateUID :: IO Int

getUID :: Int
{-# NOINLINE getUID #-}
getUID = unsafePerformIO generateUID

foo = getUID + 1
bar = getUID + 2

main = print $ (foo, bar)
```

This has the advantage that `getUID` is just a pure value, so you can use it outside of `IO` monad, if needed.

Admittedly, many people consider this a horrible hack.  Typically, a cleaner alternative is to run the program in a monad with a `Reader` component that includes the global ID value.  Usually you'll be running big chunks of any non-trivial program in some kind of monad anyway (e.g., above, you seemed willing to run `foo` and `bar` in the `IO` monad), so this is rarely much of an issue.  Something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module Uid where

import Control.Monad.Reader

data R = R { globalUid :: Int }
type M = ReaderT R IO

foreign import ccall "stdlib.h random" generateUID :: IO Int

getUID :: M Int
getUID = asks globalUid

foo = (+1) <$> getUID
bar = (+2) <$> getUID

withUid :: M a -> IO a
withUid act = do
  uid <- generateUID
  runReaderT act (R uid) 

main = withUid $ do
  liftIO . print =<< (,) <$> foo <*> bar
```