# How can I "save" a variable when repeating a function?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, repeat

Right now I'm trying to make a program that gives the sum of all numbers entered thus far. currently I have this start of the code:

```
import System.Exit

main :: IO()
main = do
    a <- getLine
    if a == "EXIT_PROGRAM"
    then
        exitWith ExitSuccess
    else
        print(a)
    main
```

It's working fine right now but you can probably tell it's not what I want. To get this I would have to save the previous sum and then add it to a, then save that and repeat the function. How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Try using recursion. Let `main = sumThings 0` and `sumThings n = ... something involving sumThings (n+k)`.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48479736/7644018) help?

Comment: well I'm not smart enough to know what's happening in that answer so sadly no, it doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way, probably should have figured it out sooner. I made a separate function that unlike main could take input. then I fed the product into it.

```
import System.Exit

multiplier :: Integer -> IO()
multiplier prevProduct = do 
    a <- getLine
    if a == "EXIT_PROGRAM"
    then
        exitWith ExitSuccess
    else
        return()
    let b = (read a :: Integer) * prevProduct
    print(b)
    multiplier b

main :: IO()
main = do
    multiplier 1
```

also I changed it so it multiplied instead of added

Comment: by the way you can also write `main = multiplier 1`

Answer (score 1):

The implementation suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72072908/126014) has the correct behaviour, but strikes me as perhaps not entirely idiomatic. Using `exitWith` strikes me as using exceptions for flow control - a technique that is frowned upon in most languages (not just Haskell).

This also leads to the need to use `return ()` for the `else` branch in order to do nothing. Here, `return ()` is used almost like `continue` in a language like C#.

Furthermore, the program will not be able to handle any errant input such as `foo`, `exit`, or even `EXIT PROGRAM`. In all such cases, it's going to crash:

```
> multiplier 1
2
2
3
6
EXIT PROGRAM
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

As *chi* suggests in a comment, using recursion would be more idiomatic, but in Haskell, you often do that by having a base case that exits cleanly.

The desired behaviour is almost a [Read Eval Print Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) (REPL), except that the evaluation function is given on beforehand. So perhaps, `readPrintLoop` might be an appropriate name. Here's one way to do it:

```
readPrintLoop :: (Show a, Read b) => (a -> b -> a) -> a -> IO ()
readPrintLoop eval acc = do
  s <- getLine
  let m = readMaybe s
  case m of
    Just x -> do
      let y = eval acc x
      print y
      readPrintLoop eval y
    Nothing -> return ()
```

This action uses [readMaybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) from `Text.Read` to parse the input with the option of failing gracefully. As a consequence, any input that doesn't parse (such as `foo`, `exit` or `EXIT_PROGRAM`) will exit the loop.

It first reads the input using `getLine`, parses with `readMaybe`, and then pattern-matches the `Maybe` value `m`.

If `m` is `Nothing`, the action exits cleanly with `()`.

If `m` is a `Just` value, it uses `eval` (a function argument) to calculate the new accumulated value, prints it, and recurses with the new accumulator.

Since the OP describes accumulating a sum, and the answer from the same user accumulates a product, I've made the `readPrintLoop` flexible by enabling the caller to define the function being used.

You can even use it to accumulate decimal numbers as well (since any `Read` instance will do):

```
> readPrintLoop (+) 0.0
1.1
1.1
2.3
3.4
exit
>
```

If, on the other hand, you want `main` to accumulate an integer product, you may define it like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  readPrintLoop (*) 1
```

Comment: The `return ()` in the OP's answer is used correctly and idiomatically to construct a do-nothing IO action; it shows no sign of being written under the common beginner misapprehension that it functions like a return statement from imperative languages. You even used `return ()` in exactly the same way because you needed a do-nothing option in one branch of the case! So that criticism is pretty strange.

Comment: @Ben you're right. I've edited the answer.